# picasso resize field on scroll up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, picasso

I have this imageview:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewHero"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

and picasso

```
Picasso.with(context).load(post.getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
```

the problem is that my recyclerview have many images, when I scroll it down it is fine but when I scroll it back up some images will load again and my cardview height will be improved again making a bad user experience.

any ideas why? how can I fix my cardview size?

Comment: Give your imageview a fixed height and set scaleType to centerCrop

Comment: @MichaelStoddart thank you very much, I'll try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `ImageView` a fixed height and set scaleType to centerCrop.

I believe this should fix your issue as the wrap content height in your ImageView is probably what is causing the jump in height

Comment: thank you very much! if I add something like: android:layout_height="1500dp" and my image height is about 400dp will it adjust to 400dp or I'll have a blank space? do you know?

Comment: @RickJoe if you use centerCrop then the image will fill the imageview regardless of image size